# jQuery | Show div when user scrolls

Tags: jquery, scroll, hide, show

I am searching for a solution to show a div when the user (horizontal) scrolls and to hide the div when the user stops scrolling. I found some code which shows a div but doesn't hide it after scrolling.

```
    $(function(){
tiles = $("ul#tiles li").fadeTo(0, 0);

$(window).scroll(function(d,h) {
    tiles.each(function(i) {
        a = $(this).offset().top + $(this).height();
        b = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
        if (a < b) $(this).fadeTo(500,1);
    });
});

});//]]>
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not really sure but maybe this would work?

```
    $(function(){
tiles = $("ul#tiles li").fadeTo(0, 0);

$(window).scroll(function(d,h) {
    tiles.each(function(i) {
        a = $(this).offset().top + $(this).height();
        b = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
        if (a < b) 
           $(this).fadeTo(500,1);
        else
          $(this).fadeOut();
    });
});

});//]]>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that did not fix it.. See http://jsfiddle.net/Qq3ET/1/ for the current situation.

Answer (score 0):

Becasue your `fadeTo(0,0)` run only one time and after scrolling finish not runned again.

You can add an event handler for the `scroll` event and start a timeout. Something like:

```
var timer = null;
$(window).addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    if(timer !== null) {
        clearTimeout(timer);        
    }
    timer = startTimeout(function() {
          // do something
    }, 150);
}, false);
```

This will start a timeout and wait 150ms. If a new `scroll` event occurred in the meantime, the timer is aborted and a new one is created. If not, the function will be executed. You probably have to adjust the timing.

Also note that IE uses a different way to attach event listeners, this should give a good introduction: [quirksmode - Advanced event registration models](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html)

Comment: :-( Nope.. Is it possible that you/someone can run the code in http://jsfiddle.net/Qq3ET/ and paste it here. Thanks!